# Mail migration from Google Workspace to Synology failed halfway. What to do?

Tags: nas, migration, google-workspace

I recently bought a Synology DS723+ so that I could migrate away from Google Workspace. I configured the MailPlus Server and started to migrate.

The first issue is that it takes forever! One of the accounts took 2 days and the one I'm currently importing has been going on for 6 hours. The one that took 2 days was my personal Google Workspace account – and it failed halfway!

Is there a way I can pinpoint why it failed so that I can complete the import? If I start the import again, will I get duplicates in my inbox?

BTW: How do I disable indexing while importing, I think it slows things down.
I've pressed stop indexing in the GUI, but it does not seem to have any effect.

Cheers,
Martin

Comment: This question needs more focus and it needs more details.

Comment: How did you migrate? Knowing what failed will depend on your migration tool/system/utility/script logging or being able to list errors it meets. Second, only one question per post, per the site rules. What makes you believe indexing is slowing things down? How much data are you moving, how fast is the slowest part of the connection between Google Workspace and your Synology? Your question needs to give us a lot more information before we could begin to formulate an answer for you. Please edit your post to include all of the information you have, the research that you have done, etc.